# Yovo screenshot blocker vulnerability

Tags: android, ios

I was studying Yovo's screenshot blocker and I noticed that when watching their demo, I was easily able to pause the video when the screenshot blocker was taking effect and get a fairly clear view of the image that was supposed to be blured.

I know that the program works using the looking through a moving fan phenomena. I'm just wondering if it has a vulnerability of recording it at a lower frame rate and taking frames from the video or do you think this is just an issue with how they made this particular video?

Here's a link to the [DEMO](https://youtu.be/fJHXy_qpQ7M). I also attached an image with the screenshot.

It's supposed to have hexagonal pattern (blured) covering the circular region on the photo, but instead if I pause it while the effect is going on, I get this:

[image: result screenshot]

I believe this is due to frame blending, but I'm not sure. Please let me know your input.

P.S.: I don't have the app since my phone is too old, so let me know if you had any experience messing with the app since I haven't had a chance to.

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: This is a question/observation for the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really prevent you from getting the image. It just makes it take more work. You could take several screenshots or a video and get all the clear pieces from the separate frames/pictures and stitch them back together.

Comment: Interesting...I'm going to look into automated blending of images. It seems there is no such thing as a screenshot blocker lol